# How to restore Ubuntu Desktop setting that's missing in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: settings, system-settings, do-release-upgrade, appearance, 22.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.10 from Ubuntu 22.04 via command line. I could see 'Ubuntu Desktop' option in settings is missing and is displaying as
[Missing Settings Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGtmA.png)
How can I restore this to working state so that I can modify dock settings.

Comment: @Raskul This isn't a forum. Comments are for requesting  additional info or clarification, not for "me toos".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem (upgraded to Ubuntu 22.10 from Ubuntu 22.04 with command line)
I re install `Gnome-Control-Center`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

then I opened the settings:

```
gnome-control-center display
```

Comment: Desktop settings are not only the Screen settings ....